# How to fetch data in Malayalalam language from MySQL and display it in browser via Java Rest API

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, encoding

In my mysql table i have data in Malayalam language (utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci). My Rest API fetching the data using jdbcTemplate and displaying it in browser. The font required to see the content is already installed in the system. But still the content is looks like the below.

Ã Â´Â¡Ã Â´Â²Ã Âµï¿½Ã¢â‚¬ï¿½Ã Â´Â¹Ã Â´Â¿Ã Â´Â¯Ã Â´Â¿Ã Â´Â²Ã Âµâ€  Ã Â´ÂªÃ ÂµÅ Ã Â´Â¤Ã Âµï¿½Ã Â´Â®Ã Â´Â°Ã Â´Â¾Ã Â´Â®Ã Â´Â¤Ã Âµï¿½Ã Â´Â¤Ã Âµï¿½Ã Â´Â®Ã Â´Â¾Ã Â´Â¯Ã

Code used to get data from db.

```
    List<News> listNewsPosts = new ArrayList<News>();
    query = "SELECT * FROM malayalam_dictionary";
    listNewsPosts = jdbcTemplate.query(query,
    new BeanPropertyRowMapper<News>(News.class));
```

This is how i am returning data to browser

```
    @GET
    @Path("/posts/)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAllPosts() {
    Date dNow = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    APIResponse apiResponse = new APIResponse();
    apiResponse.setMessage("Fetched posts successfully!");
    apiResponse.setResponseTime(ft.format(dNow));
    try {
    Map<String, Object> categories = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    categories.put("newsDetail", newsOperationsController.getAllPosts());
    apiResponse.setResponse(categories);
    return Response.ok(apiResponse).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(e, e);
    apiResponse.setMessage("Something went wrong. please try again!");
    return Response.status(500).entity(apiResponse).build();
    }
    }
```

Please help me return the API data in the correct format.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It worked after saving the class file as UTF-8 as well as changed the jdbc connection url to

```
    jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testwordprs&#63;characterEncoding=UTF-
    8&#38;useUnicode=true
```